# Getting name 'COUNTRIES' is not defined error in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i am new to Django. I want to add country field to my form. i have installed module django_countries from here : https://bitbucket.org/smileychris/django-countries

Now when i use:

```
from OpenErp_Django.django_countries import CountryField
class UserForm(forms.Form):
        country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(('', _('select country')),) + COUNTRIES)
```

I am getting following error:     name 'COUNTRIES' is not defined
I dont know what to do. I am stuck. Can Someone help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to import it

```
from OpenErp_Django.django_countries.countries import COUNTRIES
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but now i am getting a new error :     cannot import name COUNTRIES.